# how to change figure canvas size in matplotlib without altering plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

i would like to annotate panels of figures i am making with panel labels ("A", "B", ...") in matplotlib. for example i'd like to annotate a set of subplots with a large "A" in the upper left hand corner of the figure as in code below. how can i change the figure canvas to make this "A" visible?

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
# this "A" is clipped in the plot
plt.annotate("A",
             xy = (-0.25, 1.1),
             xytext = (-0.25, 1.1),
             xycoords = 'axes fraction',
             textcoords = 'axes fraction',
             fontsize=30)
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: how to make room for text label by increasing padding around subplots?]

is there a way to add "padding" to the left of the subplots, so that they are pushed to the right of the figure, without changing the `figsize` parameter? and without rescaling the plots? there is enough room in the canvas to fit the label and the subplots as they are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `plt.subplots_adjust()`:

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
# this "A" is clipped in the plot
plt.annotate("A",
             xy = (-0.25, 1.1),
             xytext = (-0.25, 1.1),
             xycoords = 'axes fraction',
             textcoords = 'axes fraction',
             fontsize=30)
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
plt.show()
```

just make sure to not put `plt.tight_layout` after `plt.subplots_adjust` as this will overwrite the changes.

Also see **[this](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust)** page on adjusting subplots.

The figure produced using the above code looks like this:
[image]